# Jquery ui slider: Set step based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to setup my jquery ui slider so that if my checkbox is not checked, it will have a step value of 0.1 or if the checkbox is checked then the step value is 1. I have very limited experience with jquery and am still learning so any help would be appreciated. Here is what I've tried so far. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h6fgb12v/)

JS

```
//Setup for jquery ui slider
harmonicSlider = $("#harmonicSlider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,

    //Updates the slider textbox with the current value of the slider.
    slide: function(event, ui){
        var harmonicSnap = $("harmonicSnap");

        setSliderBoxValue(ui.value);

        if(harmonicSnap.checked){
            $(this).slider("option", "step", 1);
        }else{
            $(this).slider("option", "step", 0.1);
        }

        var stepping = $(this).slider('option', 'step');
        console.log("Step: " + stepping);
    },

    //Gets the slider value after a change to the slider is made.
    change: function (event, ui){
        getSliderValue(ui.value);
    }
});

//Grabs the slider value and returns it.
function getSliderValue(slideVal){
    console.log("Slider Value: " + slideVal);
}

//Sets the sliderValueBox to the current value of the slider.
function setSliderBoxValue(currentValue){
    $("#sliderValueBox").val(currentValue);
}

//Sets the step of the slider depending on if the harmonics checkbox is checked or not.
function setSliderIncrement(){
    var harmonicSnap = document.getElementById("harmonicSnap");
    //var slider = $("harmonicsSlider").slider();

    if(harmonicSnap.checked){
        $("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step", 1);
        console.log("Step: " + $("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step").val());
    }else{
        $("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step", 0.1);
        //step = $("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step");
        console.log("Step: " + $("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step").val());
    }
}

//Loads the harmonic slider selector and slider labels
function loadHarmonicSlider(){
    var sliderValTextBox = $("sliderValueBox");

    harmonicSlider.each(function() {
        //Add labels to slider specified by the min, max, and step values

        var options = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;

        var values = options.max - options.min;

        //Spacing for value labels
        for(var i = 0; i <= values; i++){
            var element = $("<label>" + (i + 1) + "</label>").css("left", (i / values * 100) + "%");

            $("#harmonicSlider").append(element);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
        <div id="harmonicSliderLabel">n:</div>
        <div id="harmonicSlider"></div>
        <div id="sliderInputs">
            <input type="text" id="sliderValueBox" value="1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="harmonicSnap" value="Snap to harmonics" onchange="setSliderIncrement();" checked>Snap to harmonics
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snap selector is wrong. You're missing the # char.

Also you should use harmonicSnap.is(":checked") to check if it's checked.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdgatmdgsoftdotdk/h6fgb12v/2/)

```
var harmonicSnap = $("#snap");

setSliderBoxValue(ui.value);
if (harmonicSnap.is(":checked")) {
    $(this).slider("option", "step", 1);
} else {
    $(this).slider("option", "step", 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I completely forgot to check my selectors for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing id's all over the place in your code

```
var harmonicSnap = $("harmonicSnap");
$("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step", 1);
$("harmonicsSlider").slider("option", "step", 0.1);
```

all need to be prepended with `#`

here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6fgb12v/1/

i removed some of the broken console logs, bound the checkbox change via jquery instead of inline, and removed the step change from inside the slide (since youre binding it on checkbox change). theres still some errors from missing ids but this should put you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the input, I forgot to check for the # symbols, thats one thing about jquery I stil have to get used to!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="sliderInputs">
    <input type="text" id="sliderValueBox" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="snap" checked>Snap to whole numbers
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(function() {
   var harmonicSlider = $("#slider").slider({
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            setSliderBoxValue(ui.value);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            getSliderValue(ui.value);
        }
    });

    function getSliderValue(slideVal){
        console.log("Slider Value: " + slideVal);
    }

    function setSliderBoxValue(currentValue){
        $("#sliderValueBox").val(currentValue);
    }

    $('#snap').change(function() {
        var step = $(this).is(":checked")?1:0.1;
        $("#slider").slider({step: step});
    });
    $('#snap').change();

});
```

i'm sorry. but I updated fiddle by mistake